# Efficient derivation of finite difference schemes

Tags: soft-question, numerical-methods

What is, in your opinion, the best notation to use or practice to follow when deriving finite difference methods from Taylor expansions?

As an example of what I mean, suppose I want to find the order of accuracy for Crank Nicolson applied to the heat equation. I would difference about the point $(x,t+k/2)$:
$$
u\left(x,t+\frac{k}{2}\pm \frac{k}{2}\right) = u\left(x,t+\frac{k}{2}\right) \pm \frac{k}{2}u_{t}\left(x,t+\frac{k}{2}\right)+\frac{k^2}{8}u_{tt}\left(x,t+\frac{k}{2}\right)+O(k^3)
$$
to conclude
$$
\frac{u(x,t+k)-u(x,t)}{k} = u_t\left(x,t+\frac{k}{2}\right) + O(k^2).
$$

This I would consider annoying both to write and to read. To make it more readable and easier to write, I might suppress function arguments when it's just $(x,t+k/2)$ (i.e. when the function argument is just the point I'm differencing about).

Clearly it's not too much of a burden if you only intend to analyze one method, but if you're studying multiple schemes in a row this can get very tedious very quickly. Is there any other good practice to preserve sanity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a calculus of finite differences, based on the difference operator $\delta u=u_{j+1}-u_j$ and the averaging operator $\mu u=(u_j+u_{j+1})/2$,
both centered at $j+1/2$. With suffices we note the direction of the operator. like $\delta_x,\mu_t$ etc

The operators $\mu$, $\delta$ obey the usual rules of arithmetic. The product $\mu\delta$ is a central difference $(u_{j+1}-u_{j-1})/2$ and $\delta^2$ is the second difference $(u_{j-1}-2u_j+u_{j+1}$. There is an identity $4\mu^2+\delta^2=I$.

There is extensive literature on this but just a small subset that is useful for your purpose and I cant find a good presentation of just that subset, but you might look at the utube presentation https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6AmDhzrVq6k